# Install Zend Framework 2 site on Centos

Tags: zend-framework2, centos, setup-deployment

I'd like to install a ZF2 site on my server. I need a development version and a production version. Let's say that the development version is dev.site.com and the production version is www.site.com.

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:
Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ModuleManager\\Exception\\RuntimeException' with message
'Module (ZendDeveloperTools) could not be initialized.' in 
/usr/share/zf2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:175

Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/zf2/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(149): [...]
```

Here's my setup:

In `/usr/share/zf2/` I installed everything except the dir folder

In `/var/www/dev.site.com/public_html/` I installed the content from the dir folder (mysiteApplication)

In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf` file, i defined ZF2 Path environment variable:

`SetEnv ZF2_PATH /usr/share/zf2/library`

Also executed `export ZF2_PATH=/usr/share/zf2/library` and `service httpd restart` commands respectively.

In `/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/dev.site.com/public_html/mysiteApplication/public"
    ServerName dev.site.com
    ErrorLog "/var/www/dev.site.com/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/www/dev.site.com/requests.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/var/www/dev.site.com/public_html/mysiteApplication/application.config.php`

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../module',
        __DIR__ . '/../vendor'
 ),
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you quote your configuration files? (especially your ZendDeveloperTools config) for the buggy site?

Comment: The error is related with loading of the ZendDeveloperTools module. Can you provide your composer.json contents?

Comment: This is my composer.json.
But the error is not related to ZendDeveloperTools. It's related to the way the modules are loaded. If I remove "ZendDeveloperTools" from application.config.php then I get the same error on the next module from the list (BjyProfiler in my case)

Comment: return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'BjyProfiler',
        'OcraServiceManager',
        'RestAPI',
        'SanRestful',
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
  'ZfcAdmin',
        'StarAdmin',
        'Star',
        'Application'
    ),
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor'
        ),
        'config_glob_paths' => array('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php')
    )
);